# Android Checkboxs with ListView

Tags: android, checkbox

This is a tough situation to explain. I have a main activity that has actionbar tabs to cycle through different fragments. The first tabbed fragment that gets loaded has a listview that can scroll with checkboxes. What happens is when you first run the app, if you click on a checkbox, it doesnt check. However if you click on another tab and then click back everything works correctly.

I've looked at a lot of other situations where people havent had checkboxes work with scroll views and i've implemented their solution so i would consider my situation fixed as well due to the fact it works when you after you tab over.

Any thoughts as to why it would work the first time the view gets loaded? I know its a difficult question to ask and i dont think posting code would really help. Thanks guys.

Edit:

Here is the onCheckedChangedListener

```
public OnCheckedChangeListener checkboxContactsCallback = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            System.out.println("Checkbox checked");
            objects.getContactList().getContactList().get((Integer)buttonView.getTag(R.string.position)).setCheckbox(true);
            if(keyStoreContacts.getPublicKeyStore().size() == 0) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactsWrapperLayout);
                layout.addView(helpers.getInterfaceHelper().createDynamicButton("Delete Contact", checkboxButtonListener));
            }
            keyStoreContacts.addPublicKey((String)buttonView.getTag(R.string.publickey));
        }
        else if(!isChecked) {
            System.out.println("Checkbox unchecked");
            objects.getContactList().getContactList().get((Integer)buttonView.getTag(R.string.position)).setCheckbox(false);
            if(keyStoreContacts.getPublicKeyStore().size() <= 1) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactsWrapperLayout);
                LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)layout.findViewById(1);
                layout.removeView(layout2);
            }
            keyStoreContacts.removePublicKey((String)buttonView.getTag(R.string.publickey));
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the getView method in my array adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatable_contact_view, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.inflate_textview);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    System.out.println("Setting the checkbox " + objects.getContactList().getContactList().get(position).getIsChecked());
    checkbox.setChecked(objects.getContactList().getContactList().get(position).getIsChecked());
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(callback.getCheckboxListener());
    checkbox.setTag(R.string.publickey, objects.getContactList().getContactList().get(position).getPublicKey());
    checkbox.setTag(R.string.position, position);
    textView.setText(objects.getContactList().getContactList().get(position).getDisplayName());
    PublicKeyStore keyStore = new PublicKeyStore();
    keyStore.addPublicKey(objects.getContactList().getContactList().get(position).getPublicKey());
    contact.setTag(keyStore);
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: "i dont think posting code would really help" Then we can't help you. I would like to see a code snippet in order to do code review.

Comment: Clearly, we need the code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace you `OnCheckedChangeListener` with `View.OnClickListener` to look like this

```
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Checkable checkable = (Checkable) v;
                    if (checkable.isChecked()) {
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: has the exact same effect. When the view first loads when you click a checkbox it does not stay checked. Then if you switch tabs and go right back to it, it works correctly